# Should instead of would

Tags: grammar, should

In Red-headed League from The adventures of Sherlock Holmes, a character named Wilson describes a weird sight of hundreds of red haired men crowding the area to Holmes. By his account he had been really shocked by this crowd, yet he says 
'I should not have thought there were so many in the whole country as were brought together by that single advertisement.'
By context I think he means he wouldn't've thought it, but I don't...understand the use of 'should not have' here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the *OED* notes, this use of *should* is a colloquial expression of the "strong affirmation" of a statement.  Here

> I **should** not have thought ...

is the equivalent of

> I **definitely would** not have thought.

Answer (score 4):

In our (chiefly British) English lessons in a German high school in the late 1970s we learned that *shall* and its past *should* are simply the first person forms of "will" and "would". I think this use has since then become rare, certainly in the U.S. The use has shifted towards or focused on assertion and moral obligation ("The plaintiff shall...", "I know I shouldn't").

In your example, an American Wilson of today would probably just say "I wouldn't have thought ...".

Comment: As would a British Wilson. But perhaps not a Sir Humphrey.

Comment: I expect that use was somewhat rare even in the 1970s. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+should+not+have+thought&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20should%20not%20have%20thought%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @PeterShor Entirely possible. The text books' texts may have been a decade old, easily, and reflected past use back then.

Comment: And in high school German we were taught that _sollen_ is exactly the same as _should_... the key concept being "obligation".

Comment: @PeterShor For some reason the answer received an upvote today; I (re-?)visited your ngram and find it quite interesting. I probably had that lesson as a 12-year-old (Latin being my first foreign language) in 1976, in the later phase of its usage decline. But assuming that the book was essentially 10 years old and incorporated at the time of its writing a version of English two or three years old, it reflects a state of English that still very much used *should* as past tense of *shall.* Interesting how quickly that usage changed, in a bit more than a generation.

Comment: @PeterShor Looking at the asymptotically declining curve it is a fair bet that in 1957 the people who used it as past tense of *shall* gradually left without new writers entering the arena. The majority of the population must have grown up without it starting about 20 or so years earlier, between the wars. The old-fashioned  former majority population gradually stopped writing, and died, and thus that use disappeared with its users during the next 35 years, save a minority who continues to use it, where the curve levels out.

Comment: @PeterShor, as a student in an Australian primary school in the 1950s and 60s I was taught that *shall* and *should* were the first person versions of *will* and *would*, and the converse. Even then the modern usage was normal for us, though the "correct" usage was still found in then-current books.